# How can I transformation this sentence in interrogative?

Tags: sentence

How can I transform this sentence in interrogative?

**It matters little if he dies or not.**

Comment: Is it matters little if he dies or not?

Comment: Does it matter little whether he dies or not?

Comment: Do you want to apply a formula to transform it to an question, or do you want to know what a native English speaker would actually use to ask a question? The people who are trying to transform it using formulas are all producing very awkward sentences. I'd say *Does it really matter if he dies?*

Answer (score -3):

If you want to know the answer:

> How much does it matter if he dies or not?

If you want to hear a confirmation:

> Doesn't it matter little if he dies or not?
>
> It matters little if he dies or not, isn't it true?

Comment: These sound awkward and unnatural.